# How to compile JAR with library to apk

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, apk, jad

I get jar file with library from NetBeans and i cant convert it to apk.
Converter ask JAD and JAR files.

I have one main jar and two more in lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert .jar file to .apk!
inside a jar file we have .class files but inside the .apk we have .dex files which .dex files can convert to .class and after that .java.
so you can see a jar file is one step behind the .apk file

Answer (score 0):

Change the project(module) settings from library to application.